# Haskell: How to fix the "type variable ambigous" compiler error?

Tags: haskell, reflex

I'm using GHCJSi, version 0.2.0-7.10.3: http://www.github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs/ and the reflex-dom library version 0-4 from https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-dom. I'm not using reflex-dom-0.3 from Hackage.

The following Haskell program does not compile with reflex-dom-0.4:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo, ScopedTypeVariables, DeriveGeneric, OverloadedStrings #-}
import Reflex
import Reflex.Dom
import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.Text as T
data Apod = Apod { copyright :: T.Text
                 , date :: T.Text
                 , explanation :: T.Text
                 , hdurl :: T.Text
                 , media_type :: T.Text
                 , service_version :: T.Text
                 , title :: T.Text
                 , url :: T.Text
                 } deriving (Generic, Show)
instance FromJSON Apod
main :: IO ()
main = do
  mainWidget $ el "div" $ do
    buttonEvent <- button "GET"
    let url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY"
    let defaultReq = xhrRequest "GET" url def  
    asyncEvent <- performRequestAsync (tag (constant defaultReq) buttonEvent)
    let rspApod = fmapMaybe (\r -> decodeXhrResponse r) asyncEvent
    return ()
```

I get the error

```
 Xhr00.hs:24:36:
    No instance for (aeson-0.9.0.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.FromJSON b0)
      arising from a use of ‘decodeXhrResponse’
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      rspApod :: Event Spider b0 (bound at Xhr00.hs:24:9)
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance (aeson-0.9.0.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.FromJSON a,
                aeson-0.9.0.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.FromJSON b) =>
                aeson-0.9.0.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.FromJSON
                 (Data.These.These a b)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.These’
       In the expression: decodeXhrResponse r
    In the first argument of ‘fmapMaybe’, namely
      ‘(\ r -> decodeXhrResponse r)’
    In the expression:
      fmapMaybe (\ r -> decodeXhrResponse r) asyncEvent
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I inline the reflex-dom library function `decodeXhrResponse` (and also `decodeText`). I change the type signature `FromJSON a => XhrResponse -> Maybe a` to a signature without a type variable `XhrResponse -> Maybe Apod`. Then the program compiles successfully.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo, ScopedTypeVariables, DeriveGeneric, OverloadedStrings #-}
import Reflex
import Reflex.Dom hiding (decodeXhrResponse, decodeText)
-- import Reflex.Dom
import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Text.Encoding
data Apod = Apod { copyright :: T.Text
                 , date :: T.Text
                 , explanation :: T.Text
                 , hdurl :: T.Text
                 , media_type :: T.Text
                 , service_version :: T.Text
                 , title :: T.Text
                 , url :: T.Text
                 } deriving (Generic, Show)
instance FromJSON Apod
main :: IO ()
main = do
  mainWidget $ el "div" $ do
    buttonEvent <- button "GET"
    let nasa = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY"
    let defaultReq = xhrRequest "GET" nasa def 
    asyncEvent <- performRequestAsync (tag (constant defaultReq) buttonEvent)
    let rspApod :: Event Spider Apod = fmapMaybe (\r -> decodeXhrResponse r) asyncEvent
    return ()
-- Inlined and changed library function:
-- decodeXhrResponse :: FromJSON a => XhrResponse -> Maybe a
decodeXhrResponse :: XhrResponse -> Maybe Apod
decodeXhrResponse = join . fmap decodeText . _xhrResponse_responseText
-- Inlined and changed library function:
-- decodeText :: FromJSON a => T.Text -> Maybe a
decodeText :: T.Text -> Maybe Apod
decodeText = decode . BL.fromStrict . encodeUtf8
```

I tried to add a scoped type variable for rspApod like  `rspApod :: Event t Apod` or  `rspApod :: Event Spider Apod` but it didn't help.

Questions:

How do I have to change the first program to compile successfully? (inlining and changing a library function is a very bad hack!)

Why does the compiler not find and use the `FromJSON` instance for the data type `Apod`?

Comment: `(\r -> decodeXhrResponse r)` ~> `decodeXhrResponse`

Comment: Your original program is ambiguous. How about just adding a type signature `decodeXhrResponse r :: Maybe Apod`.

Comment: @Reid: Thanks, but changing to  `let rspApod = fmapMaybe ( \r  -> decodeXhrResponse r :: Maybe Apod) asyncEvent` does not solve the problem: Gives the same `No instance for` error. Unfortunately ...

Comment: That seems rather hard to believe...

Comment: Post above the full error after you added the type annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the function's original signature is

`decodeXhrResponse :: FromJSON a => XhrResponse -> Maybe a`

So when used the compiler needs to find the `FromJSON` instance for a given `a`. In your case the `a` is `Apod`, so the compiler should fine the `FromJSON` instance for `Apod`. In your code, there is no way for the compiler to know that is your intention. This is a common problem when parsing, where the compiler needs to be told what the goal type is supposed to be.

Now you could argue that it should be able to determine the goal type by the surrounding code like `asyncEvent`, but its not for some reason. It might be that the surrounding code is just as generic. Consider the following scenario:

`main = print $ read x`

How can the compiler know the target type for reading `x`?

`read :: Read a => String -> a` obviously this doesn't inform it of the target.

`print :: Show a => a -> IO ()` and this just asserts that the `a` must have a `Show` instance.

`a` is too generic to be parsed to, we need a concrete type.

So when when inlined the functions and changed the type signatures to include `Apod` you gave the compiler the information it needs to know what `FromJSON` instance to look up.

Here is how I would have solved this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  mainWidget $ el "div" $ do
    buttonEvent <- button "GET"
    let url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY"
    let defaultReq = xhrRequest "GET" url def  
    asyncEvent <- performRequestAsync (tag (constant defaultReq) buttonEvent)
    let rspApod = fmapMaybe (\r -> decodeXhrResponse r :: Maybe Apod) asyncEvent
    return ()
```

Adding the `:: Maybe Apod` inline type annotation should give the compiler the information it needs to know your intended parse goal. It reasonable to use type signatures in this way, since it's actually effectful.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Many thanks for your kind explanation and your solution. Your solution is the same as the one from Reid. Unfortunately, it does not help

Comment: Even if I annotate the on both sides  `let rspApod :: Event Spider (Maybe Apod) = fmap (\r -> decodeXhrResponse r :: Maybe Apod) asyncEvent`, I still get the error `No instance for (aeson-0.9.0.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.FromJSON Apod) arising from a use of ‘decodeXhrResponse’

Comment: I added an additional `instance FromJSON (Maybe Apod)` declaration and I got 2 errors: `Overlapping instances for FromJSON (Maybe Apod)
      arising from a use of ‘aeson-1.0.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON.$gdmparseJSON’` and `No instance for (aeson-0.9.0.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.FromJSON Apod)`. It seems, that there are 2 different versions of Data.Aeson 1.0 and 0.9!! How is this possible ??

Comment: @Reid: After I reinstalled ghcjs, reflex and relex-dom your solution is working! Many Thanks for your help

Comment: @Fresheyball: After I reinstalled ghcjs, reflex and relex-dom your solution is working! Many Thanks for your help